# Different results running the same Keras neural net on 2 computers

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I've got a MacBook Pro and a deep learning computer with a 1080 TI. When I run the exact same neural net on the same data, I get vastly different results. On my MacBook Pro, validation accuracy at epoch 10 is 95% and 99% by epoch 50. On the computer, validation accuracy peaks at 92%.

I looked the Keras backend doc (keras.json) and those are the same:

```
"image_dim_ordering": "tf",
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"backend": "tensorflow",
"floatx": "float32"
```

**What could be causing the discrepancy?**

Comment: Maybe simply random weight initialization. Or maybe float32 x float64?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this:
1) Different versions of keras or tensorflow on the systems
2) You forgot to set the `seed` in your original code for reproducible results.
3) If you are using python2, then you need to use this too: `os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'`